# success message not displayed if only one row is inserted

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form for entering scores for all students in a class. I noticed that when scores are entered for all the students and I click on save, the success message is displayed. 
 
 However, when I enter scores for just 1 or 2 students, it saves fine also, but the success message is not displayed. 
 
 This is confusing to a lot of my users who feel that their scores entry have not been saved and feel the need to re-enter the scores again or continuously cross-check. 
 
How do I resolve this issue?

Below is code:

```
 public function entrymarks()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', 'Subject', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $data = array(
                'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => form_error('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
            );
            $array = array('status' => 0, 'error' => $data);
            echo json_encode($array);
        } else {

            $exam_group_student_id = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_id');
           
            $insert_array          = array();
            $update_array          = array();
            if (!empty($exam_group_student_id)) {
                foreach ($exam_group_student_id as $exam_group_student_key => $exam_group_student_value) {
                    $attendance_post = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                    if (isset($attendance_post)) {
                        $attendance = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                    } else {
                        $attendance = "present";
                    }

                     $cal1 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal2 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca2_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal3 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca3_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal4 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca4_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal5 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca5_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal6 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca6_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal7 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca7_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal8 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca8_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $cal9 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca9_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                     $exam = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_exam_' . $exam_group_student_value);

                     $total = $cal1 + $cal2 + $cal3 + $cal4 + $cal5 + $cal6 + $cal7 + $cal8 + $cal9 + $exam;

                   if ($total > 0) {
                    $array = array(
                        'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
                        'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
                        'attendence'                             => $attendance,
                        'get_ca1' => $cal1,
                        'get_ca2' => $cal2,
                        'get_ca3' => $cal3,
                        'get_ca4' => $cal4,
                        'get_ca5' => $cal5,
                        'get_ca6' => $cal6,
                        'get_ca7' => $cal7,
                        'get_ca8' => $cal8,
                        'get_ca9' => $cal9,
                        'get_exam' => $exam,
                        'get_tot_score' => $total,
                        'rem1' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_rem1_' . $exam_group_student_value),
                        'note' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_note_' . $exam_group_student_value),
                    );
                    $insert_array[] = $array;
                }
            }
            }          
            $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);

          
            $array = array('status' => '1', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
            echo json_encode($array);
        }
    }
```

model

```
    public function add_result($insert_array) {

        $this->db->trans_start(); # Starting Transaction
        $this->db->trans_strict(false); # See Note 01. If you wish can remove as well

        if (!empty($insert_array)) {
            foreach ($insert_array as $student_key => $student_value) {

                $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'];
                $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id'];

                $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id']);
                $this->db->where('exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id', $student_value['exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id']);
                $q = $this->db->get('exam_group_exam_results');

                if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                    $update_result = $q->row();
                    $this->db->where('id', $update_result->id);
                    $this->db->update('exam_group_exam_results', $student_value);
                } else {

                    $this->db->insert('exam_group_exam_results', $student_value);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->db->trans_complete(); # Completing transaction

        /* Optional */

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
            # Something went wrong.
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return false;
        } else {
            # Everything is Perfect.
            # Committing data to the database.
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should put data model of your post data in the comment.. However, most likely the message does not appear is because there is an error in the middle of `entrymarks` function, even though the valid data still stored in db.. If you expecting that behavior, you have to find the error and add some condition, otherwise you can use `db trans_begin` and `commit` / `rollback`

Comment: I've added the model code and I can't seem to find any error in the ```entrymarks``` function.